# Binomial glm in `rsq` package: error: object not found

Tags: r

It seems that whenever I use any of the `rsq` package functions (`pcor` for partial correlations; `rsq` and `rsq.partial` for R-squared) on a binomial glm which uses the two-column notation, I get an error - see below. The model actually is correct, fit goes perfectly, no data missing.

Is there something I can do about it?

Reproducible example:

```
require(rsq)
data(esoph)
model1 <- glm(cbind(ncases, ncontrols) ~ agegp + tobgp * alcgp,
              data = esoph, family = binomial)

pcor(model1)
```

> Error in cbind(ncases, ncontrols) : object 'ncases' not found

```
rsq(model1)
```

> Error in cbind(ncases, ncontrols) : object 'ncases' not found

```
rsq.partial(model1)
```

> Error in cbind(ncases, ncontrols) : object 'ncases' not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `attach(esoph)` before applying the model. Like

```
data(esoph)


model1 <- glm(cbind(ncases, ncontrols) ~ agegp + tobgp * alcgp,
              data = esoph, family = binomial)

attach(esoph)
pcor(model1)
# $adjustment
#[1] FALSE
#$variable
#[1] "agegp"       "tobgp"       "alcgp"       "tobgp:alcgp"
#$partial.cor
#[1] 0.8092124 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3815876

#Warning message:
#In (nLevels > 1) & (varcls == "factor") :
#longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

rsq(model1)
# [1] 0.826124

rsq.partial(model1)
#$adjustment
#[1] FALSE
#$variable
#[1] "agegp"       "tobgp"       "alcgp"       "tobgp:alcgp"
#$partial.rsq
#[1]  6.548247e-01 -6.661338e-16  0.000000e+00  1.456091e-01

detach(esoph)
```

Comment: yeah, I just found it myself right now! Not the cleanest solution (`attach` is bad practice), but works. I improved your answer a bit so that the dirty-ness is reduced :-)

Answer (score 1):

`cbind`ing beforehand works.

```
esoph$ncases.ncontrols <- with(esoph, cbind(ncases, ncontrols))
glm(ncases.ncontrols ~ agegp + tobgp * alcgp, data=esoph, family=binomial)
```

Comes a warning though in `pcor()`.